# Resize Image with SDWebImage in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage in UITableView. 
I need to create cell sizes based on image frame and I'm using this method:

```
-(UIImage *)imageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager transformDownloadedImage:(UIImage *)image withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{



    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.cmImage.frame.size.width, self.cmImage.frame.size.width * image.size.height / image.size.width);
    // Create a graphics image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    // draw in new context, with the new size
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];

    // Get the new image from the context
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // End the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;

}
```

I called this on

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.delegate = self;
}
```

and on **cellForRowAtIndexPath** I did this:

```
 [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_model.data] options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
            self.cmImage.image = image;
        }];
```

to resize image and change frame of cmImage in cell

but I think this method responds too late for creating frame of cmImage and some images are resizing after I scroll tableView and for some cells I have different images loaded

I also got warning **[UIView frame] must be used from main thread only** from this line:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.cmImage.frame.size.width, self.cmImage.frame.size.width * image.size.height / image.size.width);
```

what am I exactly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage download image in background thread . so:

```
[SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_model.data] options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {  
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.cmImage.image = image;
    });
}];
```

alse **cellForRowAtIndexPath** call is frequent. so you should make a place holder size on the iamgeview . resize imageview when the image download finish .

-

**---------------------- edit again-------------------------**

-

look at  the SDWebImage original note , This method is called from a global queue. so you shoud change image size on main the main queue .

```
/**
 * Allows to transform the image immediately after it has been downloaded and just before to cache it on disk and memory.
 * NOTE: This method is called from a global queue in order to not to block the main thread.
 *
 * @param imageManager The current `SDWebImageManager`
 * @param image        The image to transform
 * @param imageURL     The url of the image to transform
 *
 * @return The transformed image object.
 */
- (nullable UIImage *)imageManager:(nonnull SDWebImageManager *)imageManager transformDownloadedImage:(nullable UIImage *)image withURL:(nullable NSURL *)imageURL;
```

so replece this method with follow code

```
-(UIImage *)imageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager transformDownloadedImage:(UIImage *)image withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{

    __block UIImage *newImage = nil ;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.cmImage.frame.size.width, self.cmImage.frame.size.width * image.size.height / image.size.width);
        // Create a graphics image context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

        // draw in new context, with the new size
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];

        // Get the new image from the context
         newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        // End the context
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    });
        return newImage;
}
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: I don;t know where call this methord , can you tell me ?   **-(UIImage *)imageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager transformDownloadedImage:(UIImage *)image withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL**

Comment: inside custom cell, in method awakeFromNib I called **SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.delegate = self;**   
and implemented 
**-(UIImage *)imageManager:(SDWebImageManager *)imageManager transformDownloadedImage:(UIImage *)image withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL**

Comment: i have eidit answer again , hope finish you problem.

Comment: have ang problem?

Comment: thanks for your effort but problem still exists and it become worst!